# Is using triggers best solution for this scenario

Tags: performance, sql, stored-procedures

A large SQL transactional database has more than 100 tables (and it will grow). One of them is called **Order**. Then, there is another table **WorkLoad** which derives from Order and many other joined table which contains a list of all active order. Every time an order record is created, if it meets certain conditions, it should be instantly inserted into WorkLoad table. And finally, there is a third table **WorkLoadAggregation** which displays aggregated data grouped by date and shop and it is completely built from WorkLoad table. WorkLoadAggregation should also display live data meaning that if a record is inserted in WorkLoad table then matching date/shop aggregation should also be updated.

My idea was to handle this by triggers:

- When record is **inserted in Order table**, trigger calls stored procedure which inserts record into WorkLoad table
- When **Order record is deleted** trigger deletes the record from WorkLoad table
- When **Order record is updated** in a way that it doesn't meet WorkLoad conditions, trigger deletes the record from WorkLoad table
- When record is **inserted/deleted/updated in WorkLoad** table, trigger calls stored procedure which updates matching date/shop aggregated record in WorkLoadAggregation table

I haven't used triggers that much in such large transaction dbs and for such frequent calls. Is there anything bad in this approach? My biggest concern is usage of "chained triggers", meaning that trigger on one table activates trigger on another table. I've been reading few articles which state that developers should be very cautious when using triggers. Are there any better solutions? Should I consider any NoSQL solution?

Comment: What database are you using?  Many have a facility that lets the database build and automatically maintain an aggregate table.  Oracle has materialized views, for example, and SQL Server has indexed views.

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Most of your requirements can and should be implemented in the stored procedure logic and/or referential actions (i.e. when you delete a value that participates in the primary key, cascade the delete to foreign key references).  Triggers can become extremely difficult to maintain and troubleshoot, especially with performance problems.  I wouldn't recommend your first approach is with triggers.

Comment: @ThomasStringer I am not sure I understand your answer. What is your suggestion that I should do in this case?

Comment: @JustinCave Since these queries I use are pretty complex, I am not sure how indexed views would affect overall performance. If I run a query that populate this table at once then it runs for about 2 seconds. I am not quite familiar with how indexed view would behave in that case but I guess every time when record is inserted in Order table then indexed view query would run again fully (a second or two) and view would be updated. And then second aggregated view also...?

Comment: @JustinCave forgot to mention that query which populates WorkLoad table is using CTE

Comment: Why does `WorkLoad` have to by a physical table? Justin's suggestion is a sound one. Create a view. Making it an indexed view is optional.

Comment: `WorkLoad` should be table because it's kind of staging table which is used to populate `WorkLoadAggregation`. I did made some changes to my initial idea - `WorkLoadAggregation` is actually an indexed view which queries `WorkLoad` table. One reason why `WorkLoad` can't be an indexed view is because `WorkLoadAggregation` indexed view can't be built on top of another view

Comment: just NO! Because `When record is inserted in Order table, trigger calls stored procedure which inserts record into WorkLoad table` I'm looking for the article that explains why you shouldn't use stored procedures, that's why I didn't reply. Short story, you need to respect the rollbacks, by send data to a procedure, you lose that, hence data integrity hazard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that u should follow what *thomas Stringer* suggested in comments.

Use store-procedures to insert update and delete from order table. In that you can call any of your tables simultaneously along with the query data and perform your transactions.

Learn more about MS-SQL Store-procedures [HERE](http://goo.gl/PBskhc)

Comment: I understand stored procedures but i dont understand how can they replace triggers when it comes to triggering an event? When record is inserted in Order table how can stored procedure be automatically triggered to insert that record in other table if it's not truggered by trigger

Comment: the concept is to use store-proc to add, update, delete data from your application insted of running a direct query; or you can do something like this [link](http://goo.gl/F3sI5V)

Comment: I understand that, but i still have to use triggers that will call stored procs for crud operations, like my idea suggests? Or i am missing something here?

Comment: @ile creating procedures is kind of creating APIs to your model, triggers are more likely to reinforce or help on data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

I'll discourage the option to use triggers in such case. You might be better off thinking in API terms to your model. As the comments point out, use stored procedures, as they will be easier to debug in case something goes *not according to plan*, keep in mind that you have a quite complex situation ;-)

Some helpful references,

- [wikipedia article about triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)
- [nice answer in this website](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them)
- [another external article about the topic](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/when-to-use-triggers-and-when-not-to-24837)